# How to print prime numbers?

Tags: java

I am a beginner to java.And i am trying to print 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19

This is my thought process.the above numbers i want to print are prime numbers which means they can only be divided by themselves or the value 1.So i will need to have a condition which is if(i%i==0 || %1==0){

```
import java.util.*;
public class PrimePrinter{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter num> ");
        int input=sc.nextInt();

        for(int i=2;i<=19;i++){
            if(i%i==0&&i%1==0){
                System.out.print(i);
            }else {
                System.out.print(",");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I try to think through my codes but i wonder why it will print out 2,3,4,5...and up till 19 when i already have a condition.I will appreciate if someone will give me hints for me to work out instead of posting the solutions.

Comment: All composite numbers are also divisible by 1 and themselves, so your prime test doesn't really work.

Comment: `i%i` and `i%1` will always be `0`.

Answer (score 9):

You're only checking if they're divisible by 1 and themselves.  Every number is divisible by 1 and itself.  Prime numbers are ONLY divisible by 1 and themselves, so the naive way would be to test whether they're divisible by every other number between 1 and i.

For a more efficient way to do it, look into the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Answer (score 2):

A number is prime when it is divided by itself and by 1. And 1 is not a prime number. In your program you are dividing the number by 1 so that's wrong

```
import java.util.*;
public class PrimePrinter{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter num> ");
        int input=sc.nextInt();

        // Instead of 19 you should use "input"
        // So the program will print all the numbers which are prime till input
        for(int i=2;i<=19;i++){
            if(isPrime(i))
              System.out.print(i+", ");
            }
        }
    }

  public static boolean isPrime(int number){
    for(int i=2; i<number; i++){
      if(number%i == 0){
        return false;//number is divisible so its not prime
    }
   return true; //number is prime
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> but i wonder why it will print out 2,3,4,5...and up till 19 when i already have a condition.

Your code is testing if a number is divisible by itself or one.  But *every* number (apart from zero) is divisible by itself and one.  So (naturally) every number that you tried passes "the test".

The problem is that "the test" is wrong as a test for prime numbers.  You actually need to find numbers that are *only* divisible by themselves and one.  The simple way to do this is to test your number against every *other* number that it could be divisible by.  You can restrict this to a finite set of numbers with some simple high-school math ... based on the definition of division.

Answer (score 0):

A number is considered as prime if it is only divisible by 1 and itself. It can be identified by checking the divisibility against 2 -> SQRT(n)  (instead of n-1 , SQRT of (n) will be sufficient). There are other algorithms also available with better efficiency, but for a beginner this will be sufficient as well as efficient. The entire code snippet is provided below:

```
public class PrimeNumberTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        boolean isPrime = true;
        int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        for (int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(num); i++) {
            if(num != i && num % i == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime)
            System.out.println(num + " is prime");
        else
            System.out.println(num + " is not prime");
    }
}
```